# Is FastPath lock algorithm which is devised by Scientists at Cantaloupe-Melon University correct?

Tags: multithreading

> Currently, I am reading `<<the art of multiprocessor programming>>`, I am confused by it's `Exercise 15(P42)`, which is talked about the `FastPath Algorithm`, which is devised by Scientists at Cantaloupe-Melon University, I think it's wrong...(But it's actually right!), is there someone could help me to understand here?

> exercise 15.
> In practice, almost all lock acquisitions are `uncontended`, so the most practical measure of a lock’s performance is the number of steps needed for a thread to `acquire` a lock when no other thread is concurrently trying to acquire the lock. Scientists at Cantaloupe-Melon University have devised the following “wrapper” for an arbitrary lock, shown in Fig. 2.16. They claim that if the base Lock class provides mutual exclusion and is starvation-free, so does the FastPath lock, but it can be acquired in a constant number of steps in the absence ofcontention.Sketch an argument why they are right, or give a counter example.

> pseudo Code

```java
1.  class FastPath implements Lock{  
2.      private static ThreadLocal<Integer> myIndex;    // threadLocal, 线程局部变量，只能被当前线程write and read
3.      private Lock lock;       // who’s there
4.      private int x, y = -1;  
5.      public void lock(){  
6.          int i = myIndex.get();  
7.          x = i;              // I'm here  
8.          while(y != -1){}    // is the lock free?  
9.          y = i;              // me again?  
10.         if(x!=i)            // Am I still here?  
11.             lock.lock();  
12.     }  
13.       
14.     public void unlock(){  
15.         y = -1;  
16.         lock.unlock();  
17.     }  
18.   
}
```

> here's what i assume:

- situation 1

> there's only one thread `A`, for simply, i use the `TID` of a thread instead of myIndex, then A can ultimately enter in CS `without` invoke `lock.lock()` in 11st line since the condition in 10 line fail. That seems weird but work, cause A can enter CS in `linear time` without invoke lock(), which is the purpose of the FastPath algorithm.

- situation 2

> there are total `3` threads in system. Assume `C` is already in CS right now, and A,B `are requesting` CS seperately(A is front of B). so now, the value of the variables in system are:

```java
// in A's processing
i = A's TID;
// in B's processing
i = B's TID;
// assume that A is little quick than B, then
x = B's TID;    // cause A is front of B, so x is overwrite by B
y = C's TID;         // cause C is already in CS, so y = C's TID
```

> now both A and B are stucked in `line 8th`. Assume that C is leaving CS. then `y = -1`. both A and B can cross 8th line instantaneous, then the value of the variables in system are:

```java
x = B's TID;    // no change
y = B's TID;    // cause A is front B.
// in A's processing
i = A's TID;
// in B's processing
i = B's TID;
```

> so in B's processing, `x!=i is false`, then B can directly enter the CS `without lock.lock()`, in A's processing, `x!=i is true`, then A can enter the CS after `invoke lock.lock()`. that's not mutual eclusion!

> so could anyone tell me where i am wrong. Truly thanks!

Comment: Does the book specify that the algorithm works with more than 2 locking threads?

Comment: Nope, it's an exercise, but i think it's suit for N locking threads based on it's full description. (i put the full description in my question, besides, thanks for your answering).

Answer (score 0):

I see..., this algorithm is actually totally wrong..., my analysis is rigth.